# How can I zip and download specific files from Google Cloud Storage with PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, google-cloud-platform, zip, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud Storage account with a lot of images in one folder. My database has a link to each of these images and has them sorted into categories. I now need to create a way for a user to download all images for a specific category.

I can pull up a page for a user to view all the images in a category, but I really need a way for the user to download a zip file of these select images.

Is there a way I can zip up select files myself using Javascript or PHP?

Or, are there any third party tools I can pass the image urls into that would zip up the files and present a downloadable zip file?

Comment: How often do the files change? If not often, download the files, create a zip and upload to Cloud Storage. Otherwise, you will need to create the zip file as required. There are PHP and JavaScript (Nodel.js) libraries for creating archives. Cloud Storage does not zip files for you, so you would download first, zip, and then deliver to the customer. Edit your question with details on your environment and process so that a good answer can be created.